# Define a temporary table within an SQL "select" query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm referring to MS Access SQL. Suppose I have a column with dates of birth of a population and the decades which these dates fall into.

```
Year Decade
1971 8
1953 6
1958 6
1929 3
1930 4
```

I want to create a query which will show how many people were born in each decade of a century.

I know it's going to be something like

```
SELECT (Year mod 100) \ 10 + 1 as [Decade], Count(*) as [How many people]
FROM People
GROUP BY (Year mod 100) \ 10 + 1
```

My problem is that there might be some decades in which no one was born from my population and I still want these to show up in my query, with a zero.

My ideal solution would be defining a table on the fly, consisting of rows {1,2,3,4…}, very much like you'd do in any programming language, say in Python `decades = range(1,10)`, then creating the table with the counted people, and then joining these two together with a `left join`.

It seems not possible, but I'm a newbie to SQL and databases. Is that possible? What are other approaches?

Comment: Why create it on the fly? A permanently maintained calendar table is a legitimate design pattern

Comment: Well, I don't maintain databases so I might not be familiar with their designs. But what if I need a million numbers for some future query? Or numbers that aren't consecutive? It just feels right not to inflate the database size with strings of easily generable integers — but I might be wrong.

Comment: One thing I've learnt is to not ti hamper a design by allowing for for things that may never exist. Anyway this particular use case - showing days or months or years or decades where no actual data may exist is very common and is acheived with a calendar table. https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2021/09/calendar-table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MsAccess does not have a function like Range() that you can use. What I have done in my databases is create a table of numbers to use for cases like this.

The simplest way to create this table is by using an Excel spreadsheet to build the column of numbers (for instance, from 1 to 1,000) and then import the spreadsheet as a new table. Then make whatever adjustments are appropriate - for example, the new table should have a primary key on the numbers column, and the numbers column should probably be of a long integer data type. You could call the table [Numbers] and name the column [NumberValue] - these names are up (you could just as easily call your column [Nums] or even just [N]). But I would caution against using the name [Number] for a table or column because Number is a datatype name and MSAccess does not always play nicely with names that are SQL or VBA keywords.

Now you can use your new table with regular sql: `Select * from [Numbers] where NumberValue >= 1 and NumberValue <= 10`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It seems to be the most robust one, although the thought of storing strings of adjacent integers in tables gives me shivers. I'm right now playing with some VBA code that can create such a temporary table but your answer might be the only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a small query to generate numbers:

```sql
Select Distinct Abs([id] Mod 10) As N
From MSysObjects;
```

Save it as Ten.

Then create a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query like this:

```sql
Select 
    Ten.N As Decade, 
    Val(Nz(T.C)) As [How many people]
From 
    Ten
Left Join
    (Select Count(*) As C, [Year] Mod 10 As D
    From People
    Group By [Year] Mod 10) As T
    On Ten.N = T.D
```

Output will be similar to:

[image]

Extended example that returns that dates of this year:

```sql
SELECT 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100) AS [Date]
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2
WHERE 
    (((DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100))<=DateSerial(Year(Date()),12,31)) 
    AND 
    ((Ten_2.N)<4))
ORDER BY 
    DateSerial(Year(Date()),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use MSysObjects — although can I be sure it will contain enough records to generate the whole subset of natural numbers I need, should I need, say not 10 but 1000? Also, I thought a Cartesian query generates a Cartesian product of two or more tables, in which case it would be done not with a `join` but a comma, eg. `FROM Table1,Table2`: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm). Lastly, `[Year] Mod 10` doesn't give the decade's ordinal, `([Year] Mod 100) \ 10 + 1` does.

Comment: Well, we only know what you wrote in your question and your sample data, and that was ten. It would make it a lot easier, if we have the full story. Also, I wouldn't post my answer, if I wasn't sure it will work. _MSysObjects_ will, at any time, deliver more than 10 records. And with your definition for a decade, how would you have more than 10? Anyway, to have more - up to 10^7 - just add yet a `Ten` (example appended above). For more info, study my project [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).